# Understanding a result regarding subgroups containing the $n$-th powers of a field as a subgroup of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field which contains a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

For any Galois extension $E$ of $F$, define $B(E) = F^\times \cap E^{\times n}$.

Now let $H$ be a subgroup of $F^\times$ containing $F^{\times n}$ as a subgroup of finite index.

> **Question**: Why is $B(F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}]) \supseteq H$?

I found this in a step of a proof of [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) (Theorem 5.29).

**Own attempt**:

If $H/F^{\times n}$ is of finite index, we can write $H/F^{\times n} = \langle \bar{a}_1,\dots, \bar{a}_m \rangle$ for some $a_i \in H$ ($\bar{a}_i$ denotes the class of $a_i$ in $H/F^{\times n}$.
If $h \in H$, we need to show that $h \in B(F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}])$. We can write $\bar{b} \in H/F^{\times n}$ as a product of the $\bar{a}_i$'s. Unfortunately, this is all I have.

In particular, I have trouble dealing with the construct $B(F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}]) = F^\times \cap F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}])^{\times n} = F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}])^{\times n}$. Also, I suspect that the last field is not $F[H]$ - I may be wrong but I cannot convince myself for any fact.

Could you please help me with this question?

Comment: Can you describe the notations $F^{\times n}$ and $F[H^{\frac12}]$?

Comment: @Berci: It is $F^{\times n} = \{ x \in F^\times \, | \, \exists c \in F^\times : x = c^n \}$. The notation $F[H^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ denotes the smallest subfield of $\bar{F}/F$ which contains the set $H^{\frac{1}{n}} = \{ h^{1/n} \, | \, h \in H \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is a little hard to digest (not your fault), but there's nothing deep happening in this step.  Let $h \in H$.  By definition, $h$ is in $F^{\times}$, and $F[H^{1/n}]^{\times}$ contains all the $n$th roots of $h$.  Choose one such $n$th root and call it $h^{1/n}$.  Then $h = (h^{1/n})^n$, so $h \in (F[H^{1/n}])^{\times n}$.

Regarding the second paragraph of your attempt:  $F[H^{1/n}]^{\times n}$ is just a multiplicative group, not a field.  It contains (at a minimum) all elements of $H$, as well as all $n$th powers in $F^{\times}$.  In general, it neither contains nor is contained in $F^{\times}$.  For example:  take $F = \mathbb Q$, $n = 2$, and $H = \{\pm x^2 : x \in \mathbb Q^{\times} \}$.  Then $\mathbb Q[H^{1/2}] = \mathbb Q(i)$.  Notice that $\mathbb Q(i)^{\times 2}$ contains some irrationals, such as $(1+i)^2 = 2i$, but does not contain some rationals, such as 2.